# Using same memory region as local and remote for testing

Tags: infiniband

I am playing with infiniband HW and wanted to check if it was legal to have MR using lkey and rkey by the same thread sending and receiving RDMAs locally.

Basically, the thread/process would include the MR rkey in the data passed to post_send() and configure the sge list with MR lkey to transfer from.

Comment: not sure about the same thread/process, but two processes on a same computer can try send/recv, its call loopback ib, but you need to open only one device of which context would be shared for protection domain allocation.